# Include missing dependencies in VSTO setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, vsto, setup-project

I created a basic install for my VSTO Excel plug-in by publishing my project.

It pretty much worked ok except for some reason it missed 2 dependencies, dll's which are needed to communicate with our SAP system.

Did loads of Googling but I can't find a way to add them in Visual Studio.

I tried downloading the [setup project type from MSDN](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d), but wierdly when I built the install it included the SAP dll's but it didn't install my plug-in! There doesn't seem to be much info on how to do this with VSTO, or at least I couldn't find it.

However I note from MSDN that there are a lot of problems with that template, so it's possible it doesn't work for VSTO stuff.

So, a workaround is obviously to run both - and that works ok - but it isn't ideal and (understandably) not satisfactory for our support team.

I would think there are several ways to fix this problem, so if anyone could answer one or two of the following that would really help!

1. How can I make sure that my dependency files are included in my setup when I use `Publish`?
2. What is the correct way to create a Visual Studio 2013 Installer Project
   that works correctly with VSTO?

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an answer to question 2:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> 1.How can I make sure that my dependency files are included in my setup when I use Publish?

You need to add them as a content to the target folder or make sure that files are copied to the output folder with the add-in assembly. Right click on the reference in the Solution Explorer window and see the reference's Properties. Pay special attention to the Build Action, copy to the output folder properties and etc.

> 2.What is the correct way to create a Visual Studio 2013 Installer Project that works correctly with VSTO?

The [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article describes all the required steps for deploying Office add-ins.

Comment: Re: (1) - where can I find the Build Action? It doesn't appear in the properties list.